# How to use CameraSource to detect custom visual code which need color information

Tags: android, android-vision

I want to use `CameraSource` to detect some visual code (which is not any kind of Barcode). I implements `Detector` and its `detect(Frame frame)` method. However, when I call `frame.getBitmap()` in the `detect` method, it always returns `null`. I know `Frame` has another method, `getGrayscaleImageData()`, but detecting the code needs color information. It seems that `CameraSource` only pass the gray-scale image data to its underlying detector.

So, is there a way to detect this code by `CameraSource`? Or should I abandon `CameraSource` and find another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current release, CameraSource actually does return the full color information for the image from getGrayscaleImageData.  The leading bytes of what is returned is the grayscale layer of the image (the Y channel), but the bytes beyond that have the color information.  The format details depend upon what image format you specified in setting up the CameraSource (the default is NV21 format).

Answer (score 0):

Found it :D 
this code return colored bitmap so fast but if it's the Front camera you may have to flip/rotate according to device.

```
    public SparseArray detect(Frame frame) {
    byte[] bytes = frame.getGrayscaleImageData().array();
    YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(frame.getGrayscaleImageData().array(), ImageFormat.NV21, frame.getMetadata().getWidth(), frame.getMetadata().getHeight(), null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, frame.getMetadata().getWidth(), frame.getMetadata().getHeight()), 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] jpegArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegArray, 0, jpegArray.length);//this bitmap is colored.
    return null; 
}
```